# open cv cv::neon_cvtColorBGRA2GRAY issue

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv

I am converting an image in cartoon like, My application run well in simulator. And desired output is coming,  but problem is that when I run my app on device it gives error on below line.

```
if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
            cv::cvtColor(bgr, gray, CV_BGRA2GRAY);
else
            cv::neon_cvtColorBGRA2GRAY(bgr, gray);// got error in this line
endif
```

error :  no member name neon_cvtColorBGRA2GRAY in namespace cv

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is not a part of OpenCV. It must have been manually coded to the cv namespace. With that being said, you will need to provide the code that implements that function. After a quick search, it seems like this is what you want:

https://github.com/BloodAxe/OpenCV-Tutorial/blob/master/OpenCV%20Tutorial/cvneon.cpp

Just take this .cpp file and the respective .h file from this repo and add them to your project.